# I am not able to open the file in python even after going to the correct path

Tags: python-3.x

1. able to print the file name
2. file not found error when open command is executed.(filenotfounderror)

   ```
     for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
          print(file)   
          k=open(file,'r')
   ```

Comment: That is not properly indented. Also explain what do you mean with `I am not able to open the file` what doesn't work? Any error?

Comment: when open command is executed FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  error is coming even though file is present in the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

### The variable `files` is a list of file names

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(f)
```

By running that code, it will print a **list of files**, not including the directories.

### If you want to open each file, use this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        k=open(root+"\\"+file,'r')
```

This works because you **need** the whole file path, `root` is the file path before the file, putting them together will give you the whole path.

Comment: thanks but it is not the problem of indentation. when open command is executed file not found error is coming even though file is present in the correct path

Comment: @krishnabharadwaj Fixed it! Try that :)

Answer (score 0):

`file` is just a file name, not it's path.

You can't expect to open a file from nested directory just by it's name.

> To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in
>   dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

```
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        file_path = os.path.join(r, file)
        print(file_path)
        k = open(file_path, 'r')
```

You can look up the documentation for more info https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk and don't forget to close the file or use context manager!